# Problems with "Chosen select" in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-chosen

Hello how are you? I am having an inconvenience with a dynamic select, in which I charge the "matriz", and depending on whatever a second select charges me with the "ensayos". In the "create" form there is no problem, the problem is in the "edit" form, since when I start editing I must show the data of the selected field in "matriz" so if I have to change the Assays do not make a selection of these according to the "matriz" preloaded. For example, if when I entered the sample I put in "matriz": Water, when I enter the edit form, so that the selection of "ensayos" takes the changes, I must select another "matriz" (ex: Food) and again select "Water" so that the filter is generated again in the "ensayos" field and be able to select only the water tests.

I leave the code so you can see what I say:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="matriz">Matriz:</label><br>
     <select class="chosen-select" name="matriz_id" id="matriz">
        <option disabled selected>Seleccionar Matriz</option>
           @foreach($matrizs as $matriz)
               <option value="{{$matriz->id}}" @if(($muestra->matriz_id) == ($matriz->id)) selected="selected" @endif>{{$matriz->matriz}}</option>
           @endforeach
     </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group ml-4">
   {!! Form::Label('ensayo_id', 'Ensayos:') !!}
       <select class="chosen-select" name="ensayo_id[]" id="ensayos" multiple="multiple" style="width: 950px">
           @forelse($selects as $sel)
               @foreach($ensayos as $ensayo)
                   <option value="{{$ensayo->id}}" @if(($sel->ensayo_id) == ($ensayo->id)) selected="selected" @endif>{{$ensayo->ensayo}}</option>
               @endforeach
           @empty
               @foreach($ensayos as $ensayo)
                   <option value="{{$ensayo->id}}">{{$ensayo->ensayo}}</option>
               @endforeach
           @endforelse
       </select>
</div>
```

And this is the code in jQuery:

```
$('#matriz').change(function(e){
    var matriz_id = e.target.value;
    $.get('/dsa/public/lab/muestras/'+matriz_id+'/ensayos', function(data){ 
        $('#ensayos').empty();       
        var html_select = '';
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i)
        html_select += '<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].ensayo+'</option>';
        $('#ensayos').html(html_select);
        $('#ensayos').chosen();
        $('#ensayos').trigger("chosen:updated");   
    });
});
```

I tried to make a change in:

```
$('#matriz').change(function(e)
```

Changing to:

```
$('#matriz').ready
```

but didn't work.

Can you think of how I can fix this? From already thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think, you can load the entries of `ensayos` when the page load is finished and the correct value is being set in field `matriz`. 
I only changed two lines comparing to your code.
Run this code, when document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and then read the selected value of `matriz`

```
var matriz_id = $('#matriz').val();
```

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var matriz_id = $('#matriz').val();
    $.get('/dsa/public/lab/muestras/'+matriz_id+'/ensayos', function(data) { 
       // here your code as above
       ...
});
```

Comment: Excellent @dns_nx, I would like to ask you one last question, if I would like the field "ensayos" to keep the data already loaded, what should I change? Because I used to show it. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I actually do not understand fully what you want to achieve? What do you mean with to "keep the data already loaded"? Do you mean, you want to add the entries in the select field instead of replacing them?

Comment: I did not express myself well, when I enter data in the "create" form I put sample data in a "samples" table, and this table is related to a table called "essays" (there is a pivot table between them). So each "samples" has one or more "essays."

Comment: Continue...So every time in the "create" form I fill in the sample data and select their essays, I enter the IDs of each table in the pivot. When I enter to edit this sample, with the change you told me, now in the field "essays" it leaves me empty, it does not bring me the essays that I had previously loaded in the "create" form.
I hope it is clear, thank you very much

Comment: I already solved it, modifying the controller, the code was even clearer. Thank you